# How to pass data from a class file to a razor page?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make a server program with a web UI using blazor server. But i'm not able to find a way to pass data from my server class to my index file. In this project, i have 2 main problems.

1 - The UI doesn't refresh when a client connects to the server and has its object stored in a dictionary.

2 - I can't figure out how to pass error messages from my server class to the razor file (index).

Even though i'm trying to make these stuffs directly from my server class, i'd like to make them from a middleware class, which will receive data from the server class and then pass to my index file.

What i'd like to do:

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@using System.Net.Sockets
@using System.Threading
@inject Server server

<table class="table">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Dispositivos</th>
            <th scope="col">IP</th>
            <th scope="col">Porta</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Servidor</td>
            <td>127.0.0.1</td>
            <td>8600</td>
        </tr>
        @* Remove this and get data from my middleware class *@
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TcpClient> client in server._connectedClients)
        {
            string endpoint = client.Value.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            string ip = endpoint.Split(":")[0];
            string port = endpoint.Split(":")[1];
            string device = client.Key;

            <tr>
                <td>@device</td>
                <td>@ip</td>
                <td>@port</td>
            </tr>
        }
  </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(() => server.Start());
        serverThread.Start();
    }
}
```

**Middleware class**

```
class Middleware {
    public string[] AddDeviceEntry(string device, string endpoint) {
       // Return this object to index.razor somehow and update the UI
       return new string[] { device, endpoint }; 
    }

    public string ErrorMessage(string msg) {
        // Return this object to index.razor somehow and update the UI
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
class Server {
    private TcpListener _server;
    private Middleware _mid;
    public Dictionary<string, TcpClient> _connectedClients = new();

    public Server(int portNum, Middleware middleware) {
        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portNum);
        _mid = middleware;
    }

    // Some stuffs...

    // When client connects
    _connectedClients.Add("some device", client);
    _mid.AddDeviceEntry("some device", client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

    // When getting some error
    _mid.ErrorMessage("some error message");
}
```